# Sync calendars over LAN?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, lan, calendar, lightning

I need access to my father's calendar on Outlook, so I suggested that we put his calendar in a shared folder on our LAN. Problem is, I use Thunderbird(Lightning extension) and he uses Outlook, so his calendar will have to be exported regularly (ideally once a day) in an iCal format and then posted to the LAN. Is there some way to do this in Outlook (export calendar regularly) or will I need to write a script, and if so how can I write that script?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to synch calendars via lan?

Answer (score 3):

Before my family moved to another system, I synced all the calenders to [iCalX](http://www.icalx.com/). You could also try Google Calender, but you are going to need a central account to sync your stuff to (family account?).

Don't try and do in house syncing. It's way too difficult.

Comment: Security/ paranoia is a concern, however. Could I rig outlook to push calendar updates to google calendar or icalx?

Comment: Yes, with both options its 2 way synchronization. IcalX can do private calenders, and google calenders are hidden by default

Comment: I suggest google calendar for anyone wanting to share/sync calendars.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried google calendar sync? It's compatible with Outlook 2007 and 2010. You can then sync your thunderbird with the google calendar.